# Is $\pi$ periodic in any numeral system?

Tags: number-theory, pi, number-systems

Is $\pi$ periodic in any base-k numeral system, where k is integer ? And what is the status of this problem?

Comment: Yes. For example, in base $\pi$, $\pi$ is written $10$.

Comment: No, periodic numbers are algebraic (or even rational), $\pi$ is neither.

Comment: Evidently, it depends on what you mean by "numeral system."

Comment: @Chris Eagle:  how do you write numbers in base $\pi$?

Comment: @JoelCohen: The same way you do for any other base. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-integer_representation for example.

Comment: @ChrisEagle:  This might  bake your noodle, but: is pi rational, then, in base pi?  Is it really a member of R, the reals (or is that an artifact of base 10 bias)?

Comment: @ChrisEagle:  When you write in octal, you use the numbers 0-7.  What numbers do you use in base pi?

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  If the base system was an irrational number, the pi could potentially be periodic, yes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. In order for $\pi$ to be periodic in base $k$, it must be true that $\pi \equiv m(\pi) \pmod{k}$ for some integer $m$.

By definition of mod, this means that $m(\pi) = \pi + nk$ $\Rightarrow$ $\pi = nk/(m-1)$, which is rational. Since we know that $\pi$ is irrational, we get a contradiction.

In fact you can apply the same argument for all irrational numbers. You can conclude that any irrational number is non-periodic in $k$.

Answer (score 12):

$\pi$ is irrational - that was settled hundreds of years ago. That implies that the expression of $\pi$ to any integer base $b$ will be aperiodic. If you have some other kind of numeral system in mind, please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: But what of the case of numerical system in base-$\pi$?

Comment: @MAR, that's already answered in some of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

According to the wikipedia article on non-integer representation in base $\pi$ the circumference of a circle of diameter $1$ is $\pi$, which is represented by $10_{\pi}$. This is the base $\pi$ representation of $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\pi$ were periodic in any base, then it would be rational, and therefore periodic in every base.  This does not happen.

Answer (score -1):

Not for an integer base, but it just happens that $\pi=0.1111111...=0.\bar{1}$ in base $\kappa=\frac{1}{\pi}+1 \approx 1.31831$. :)