# Let $x$ be an irrational number. Is the set $\ \{nx \mod 1: n \in \mathbb{N} \}\ $ dense in $[0,1]\ ?$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, real-numbers

Let $x$ be an irrational number. Is the set $\ \{nx \mod 1: n \in \mathbb{N} \}\ $ dense in $[0,1]\ ?$

Obviously if $x$ were rational, the set would be finite and therefore would have no limit points, so my question follows naturally.

Certainly, the set must have at least one limit point in $[0,1],\ $ e.g. see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141712/is-pi-periodic-in-any-numeral-system/141728#141728).

If the answer is no, how do we find the set of limit points in $[0,1]\ ?$

I had a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215536/finding-limit-points-of-the-set-m-sqrt2-nm-n-in-mathbbn), but I'm not sure it's the same question and I'm not very knowledgeable on continued fractions.

Comment: This is (part of) the [Weyl Equidistribution Theroem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75777/elementary-proof-of-the-equidistribution-theorem)

Comment: This seems to have been asked and answered before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/450493/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/903142/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/843763/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/272545/42969

Comment: Ah, thank you. I guess we should close the question then.